# How to manage shared Models/Entities of Microservices in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data-jpa, microservices, spring-cloud

I'm working on my first spring cloud project ever and I ran into a problem, I have models/entities being repeated everywhere, is there a better way to structure things?

[Project structure picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GhVW.png)

Since I'm just starting out with the project, I will have to make a lot of changes to these entities, which means replacing all the older versions in other modules. Is there a way to just made them once and every module can use them? I'm using spring data JPA so these entities are also mapped out into tables.

Comment: If you are sharing entities between microservices and share a database, you are doing it wrong. You should be sharing contracts (json, xml or whatever you use).

Comment: I suggest creating an aggregator service : https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/design-patterns-for-microservices-aggregator-pattern-99c122ac6b73#:~:text=In%20IT%20industry%2C%20aggregator%20refers,responds%20to%20the%20initiating%20request.

Comment: @M.Deinum but To set up relationships between tables in the entities I need those other entire classes to be present in the microservice module

Comment: @itsDanial 'To set up relationships between tables in the entities' is exactly what you should NOT be doing with microservices, if those entities belong to different subdomains

Answer (score 0):

**Good question !**

Probably this article can help here

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535775/should-i-share-models-across-multiple-microservices#:~:text=The%20whole%20point%20of%20microservices,you%20binding%20to%20a%20minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535775/should-i-share-models-across-multiple-microservices#:%7E:text=The%20whole%20point%20of%20microservices,you%20binding%20to%20a%20minimum).

As mentioned by community, we only must share contracts and complete Models/Entities might not be necessary !