# Java spring - sharing domain models across projects

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

Let's say I have a Book class as below in a library (library does not include spring boot). This needs to be shared across multiple services each maintaining their own DB and could add additional fields to the POJO. One of the services uses spring boot. Can I somehow use the Book class in the library as a domain model and have a JpaRepository created with it?

```
@Data
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String isbn;
    private double price;
}
```

Or is there any other suggestion to share the Book class across different services. I am trying to find a solution where I do not have to duplicate this class across all services.

Comment: By multiple services you mean microservices?

Comment: Yes, they are microservices

Answer (score 2):

You should not share `Book` class between different services. Each of those service has a different understanding of what a "Book" is, especially that you mentioned that they will have different set of extra properties.

Create separate domain classes in each service. Some of properties may repeat, that's fine.

Ideally individual services should share as little as possible (of course a schema of some DTO objects used for inter-service communication may be exception).

Comment: The problem is we have a lot of common logic and don’t want to duplicate it across services. So to have the common logic in a library we need the shared models.

Comment: 'have a lot of common logic' sounds for me it should rather be a single microservice then serveral microservices. Just somehow splitting applicaiton logic doesn't make it a microservice architecture. It's the semantic of the bounded contexts you should consider for splitting it

Comment: I understand that, but there is no doubt these are different microservices. They are worlds apart, but the current feature is common across these services. Also, we are beyond the point of having a new service for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to share a model with multiple microservices, because it adds a coupling between these microservices. One of the greatest advanteges of microservices is to develop them independently, wich you will lose with coupling.

See these questions and answers for more details about it:

- [Should I share models across multiple microservices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535775/should-i-share-models-across-multiple-microservices)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290922/shared-domain-model-between-different-microservices