# Sharing types between microservices?

Tags: types, architecture, microservices

I'm still learning about micro-services, but I know it's a bad design to share objects between services, in a micro-service architecture, because if you need to reuse an object it means you didn't split your services well enough.

But would it be a bad idea to share your object/types NOT to reuse the objects themselves, but in order to improve the coding experience (with attribute autocompletion) and to fail builds if something changed somewhere ??

Ex: You have 2 micro-services, A(sales) and B(products). A asks B for a product P, and parses P to get multiple attributes (x,y,z) from it, in order the calculate the final price. But then if some dev changes the structure of a product (ex: renames z to j), it breaks A, because A is looking for z. But, if you shared what the objects P looks like, globally, A would instead know that z doesn't exist anymore from P and will throw a proper error during development or build. It should theoretically prevent lots of errors from reaching prod.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67538613/11187832), which says " When service B is using the output of service A, only map the bits that you need for service B. service B should have its own independent model which only cares about the things from service A that B cares about.". But I'm exactly talking about this "map the bits that you need" part, that would, this idea, look like this :

```ts
import { Bproduct } from globalTypesPackage // this package would have all the objects of all your services. 

var origP:Bproduct = await getPFromB()
var altP = new Aproduct(origP.x, origP.y, origP.z)
// Here we have an Aproduct object, specific to the A service. 
// we don't reuse Bproduct as an active object in service A, but only to help catch errors during the mapping, if z doesn't exist, user will get an error, next build will throw an error.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that if by "objects" we understand simple DTOs which represent service contracts then it can be acceptable.

In ideal world services should share between each other only their contracts (you can look into [schema registry](https://www.redhat.com/architect/schema-registry) for example) but at different stages of application development depending on technologies used, available infrastructure and team size you can use the quick-and-dirty approach of sharing packages/libraries with contracts. Though it have some downsides - for example you will be restricted to using the same technology stack for all services (which sometimes is actually ok).

Answer (score 0):

Client stubs are a tried-and true method of keeping your contracts consistent and easing consumption of your services.   However, they are also significant overhead, and the publication and distribution of them can become a huge headache that can paralyze an organization.

They ultimately end up being transitive and composed, which recreates the monolith in a distributed way, requiring careful coordination and simultaneous release cadences (the very thing you were trying to solve by going to microservices).

Think about the scenario of how you are going to leverage these client contract stubs.  In order the ensure their value, you will have to build and deploy your application every time one of these services updates, so that you will catch the errors provided by the updated contracts.  This ties you to a release on EVERY microservice update.  Since you have to have that coordination, you will also want to start batching your microservice updates so that you can minimize the incremental build and deploys of your main application (because that has the most chance of user impact, and requires the regression testing).  At some point, very soon, you will end up having a giant release in which you version and deploy all of these as a distributed monolith, and ***you will have all the disadvantages of a monolith, plus all the disadvantages of microservices.***  I have seen this story happen in real life.

I would recommend instead, invest more into ensuring your microservices handle request and response versioning, so that the application can have controlled migration to new versions of APIs.  Use your APIs as data-sources, create data-access stubs that only deal with the bits they need, and test them in the client applications as you move from version to version of your application.  This way your testing and release cycles are independent for the various parts of the application and you avoid turning your system into a distributed monolith.